# NSMutableDictionary does not sort correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

Let i have unsorted **NSMutableDictionary**

```
    {
        A = "3";
        B = "2"; 
        C = "4";
    }
```

And i need result to be like:

```
    {
        B = "2";
        A = "3";
        C = "4";
    }
```

How can i achieve this result in **objective c**.

A simple code implementation will be appreciated.

Comment: share your code first :)

Comment: @AmitPatel `NSArray *sortedValues = [[myDict allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];`
now i am confused how to sort there keys?

Comment: here in your code you sorting only values of NSMutableDictionary...you also need to create another NSMutableDictionary then store it with specific key that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not sort **NSMutableDictionary** by value as @joe and @mavrick3 answer. However if you change there keys and values to **NSArray** you can do it..
Here is simple implementation..
NSMutableDictionary *results; //dictionary to be sorted

> ```
>     NSMutableDictionary *results; //dict to be sorted
>     NSArray *sortedKeys = [results keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
>         if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) 
>             return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
>         if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue])
>             return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending; 
>         return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
>     }];
>     NSArray *sortedValues = [[results allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
>
>     //Descending order
>     for (int s = ([sortedValues count]-1); s >= 0; s--) {
>         NSLog(@" %@ = %@",[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:s],[sortedValues objectAtIndex:s]); 
>     }
>     //Ascending order
>     for (int s = 0; s < [sortedValues count]; s++) {
>         NSLog(@" %@ = %@",[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:s],[sortedValues objectAtIndex:s]); 
>     }
> ```

Comment: Here is a very good [tutorial](http://www.programmerscountry.com/tutorial-sort-nsmutabledictionary-keys-by-values/) on this.

Comment: can you plz tell me what is the `results` varaiable in the above code. Is it a **NSMutableDictionary**?

Comment: Sorry, yes this is **NSMutableDictionary** i have edited my answer, it is now more clear..

Answer (score 7):

Not possible with an NSMutableDictionary, it is not a sorted structure. You will have to turn it into an NSArray and then sort that. You will then not have a dictionary structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to sort your Dictionary.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"6",@"A",@"3",@"B",@"5",@"C",@"2",@"D",@"21",@"F",@"20",@"G",nil];


NSArray *sortedArray = [tmpDict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1,id obj2){


    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];


}];

NSLog(@"Sorted = %@",sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary`as well as `NSMutableDictionary` cannot be sorted by value. You can only use a `NSArray` to sort them. But you have to this with your own code and you won't get the same output as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do this

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2", @"4", @"1", nil];
NSArray *sorted = [arr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSLog(@"Pre sort : %@", arr);
NSLog(@"After sort : %@", sorted);
```

If you have f.ex. array of dictionary (or model objects), you could do this :

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Mannie" forKey:@"name"];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Zannie" forKey:@"name"];
NSDictionary *dict3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Cannie" forKey:@"name"];
NSArray *peopleIKnow = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict1, dict2, dict3, nil];

NSSortDescriptor *sorty = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

NSArray *results = [peopleIKnow sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorty]];

NSLog(@"Before : %@", peopleIKnow);
NSLog(@"After : %@", results);
```